# Discord.py - How to retain argument for use with view?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Using discord.py, I've got a command that takes an argument and returns data from a .yml file entry of the same name. It's a lot of data per entry, so what I'm trying to do is split it up into multiple pages, which should be able to be switched between with buttons.

However, I can't find a way to make a button view retain the argument that the user inputted (it's a slash command). I kind of need this to access the relevant data.

Here is the command and the view which I've got right now (I plan to add more buttons for the view):

```
@client.tree.command()
@app_commands.describe(
    entry="The enemy ID (0 - 230)"
)
async def enemy(interaction: discord.Interaction, entry: app_commands.Range[int, 0, 230]):
    """Look up enemy data from enemy_configuration_table.yml"""

    file = discord.File(f"BattleSprites/{entry}.png", filename = "battle_sprite.png")
    
    embed=discord.Embed(title=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Name'], color=0xdb0000)
    embed.set_author(name=f"Enemy {entry}")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://battle_sprite.png")
    embed.add_field(name="HP", value=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['HP'], inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="PP", value=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['PP'], inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Offense", value=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Offense'], inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Defense", value=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Defense'], inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Luck", value=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Luck'], inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Guts", value=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Guts'], inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Speed", value=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Speed'], inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Exp.", value=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Experience points'], inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Money", value=f"${enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Money']}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Level", value=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Level'], inline=True)
    
    await interaction.response.send_message(file=file, embed=embed, view=enemyButtons())
```

```
class enemyButtons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout=180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
    @discord.ui.button(label="Sprites",style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def gray_button(self,button:discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):#, entry: app_commands.Range[int, 0, 230]): <- I've tried including this but it doesn't work.

        file = discord.File(f"SpriteGroups/{enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Overworld Sprite']}.png", filename = "overworld_sprite.png")
        embed=discord.Embed(title=enemy_configuration_table[entry]['Name'], color=0xdb0000)
        embed.set_author(name=f"Enemy {entry}")
        embed.set_image(url="attatchment://overworld_sprite.png")
        await interaction.response.edit_message(file=file, embed=embed, view=enemyButtons())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always pass the data you want to keep to the `View` class and store it as a class variable.

So:

```py
class EnemyButtons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, some_data, timeout=180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.some_data = some_data
 
    @discord.ui.button(label="Sprites", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def gray_button(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        # use that data here
        print(f"Look at my data: {self.some_data}")
```

Then, when you instantiate your View within the slash command:

```py
@client.tree.command()
@app_commands.describe(entry="The enemy ID (0 - 230)")
async def enemy(interaction: discord.Interaction, entry: app_commands.Range[int, 0, 230]):
    # give the view the entry number or whatever else you want
    view = EnemyButtons(entry)
    await interaction.response.edit_message(view=enemyButtons())
```

I've obviously trimmed down the functions/class to make it easier for this example. But you can have as many parameters in `__init__` that you need.